# How to decrypt data with a ECDSA private key?

Tags: go, encryption, public-key-encryption, ecdsa

I am writing an application where I want only the owner of a specific `*ecdsa.PrivateKey` to decrypt a piece of data. The encryption part hasn't been done yet. Nothing has been done yet in fact. I am starting with the decrypting part.

Therefore, assuming a string has been encrypted with an `*ecdsa.PublicKey` - as I understand Public Key Cryptography, only the correspondent `*ecdsa.PrivateKey` can decrypt that data.

```
func decrypt(key *ecdsa.PrivateKey, data []byte) error {
   //???
}
```

How can I decrypt such data in golang?
The only helpful reference I found is by using decreds secp256k1 package - but that doesn't use an `*ecdsa.PrivateKey` as the key, but a `secp256k1` key.

Other useful examples show how to sign data with it. But not how to decrypt a piece of data.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something here?

```
func decrypt(key *ecdsa.PrivateKey, data []byte) error {
  secp256k1.Decrypt(key, data) // obviously doesn't work: key is not the same type
}
```

Comment: ecdsa is the Elliptic Curve Digital *Signature* Algorithm. It's not designed for general purpose encryption.

Comment: I understand you mean to say that it's not possible, then...

Comment: I don't know if it's impossible in general. It is impossible with Go's standard library. But it is certainly inadvisable to use a cryptographic operation or algorithm in ways it was not intended because you have no security guarantees.

Comment: Actually, it is possible. There is really no such thing as an ECDSA key pair, only EC key pairs. ECDH can use the same keys. ECDH (and key agreement in general) can be used to implement [(EC)IES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme), where a message specific ephemeral key pair is created, a symmetric key is derived used for encryption, and then the ciphertext can be send with the ephemeral public key.

Comment: Beware that there are some (superficial) differences for Ed25519 and Ex25519 key pairs. That letter difference is in there for a reason. Same thing for 448 / goldilocks curve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are interested in encrypting and decrypting data using elliptic curve cryptography in Go. However, the `ECDSA` (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) is actually designed for digital signatures, not encryption. It's used for signing data and verifying those signatures, which is a bit different from the encrypt/decrypt process you're asking about.

We do have another elliptic curve algorithm called `ECIES` (Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme), which is made for encryption and decryption. Unfortunately, Go doesn't offer built-in support for ECIES. But the good news is that there are other libraries out there that do, like the `go-ethereum` crypto library.

Here's an example using [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum). First, we create an `ECDSA` key pair. Then, we use the public key to encrypt a message, and the private key to decrypt it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    // First, we'll generate a new ECDSA private key
    privateKeyECDSA, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Oops! Something went wrong generating the private key: %v", err)
    }

    // Now, let's get the public key from the private key
    publicKeyECDSA := privateKeyECDSA.Public()

    // We'll try encrypting and decrypting a simple message: "hello, world!"
    message := []byte("hello, world!")

    // Now, let's encrypt the message with our public key
    ciphertext, err := crypto.Encrypt(message, publicKeyECDSA.(*ecdsa.PublicKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Oh no! The encryption didn't work: %v", err)
    }

    // Finally, let's decrypt the message with our private key
    plaintext, err := crypto.Decrypt(ciphertext, privateKeyECDSA)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Yikes! We ran into an issue decrypting the message: %v", err)
    }

    // If everything went smoothly, this will print: hello, world!
    fmt.Println(string(plaintext))
}
```

Just a heads up before you go ahead, encrypting actual data directly with public key encryption works for small data, but it's not so great for larger data. This is because there's a limit to the amount of data you can encrypt with public key encryption.

So, for bigger data, a common way is to generate a random symmetric key, use it to encrypt the actual data with a symmetric encryption algorithm (like AES), then encrypt the symmetric key with the public key, and send both to the recipient. The recipient can then use their private key to get the symmetric key back, and use it to decrypt the actual data.

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, in fact my app is in the crypto space, so it applies very well. My data is just a URL string, not too big.

However, I can't find such a `Decrypt` function in `go-ethereum`'s crypto package?